# Rails Rspec with loop and subject of multiple similar test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a couple same tests, the only different is the arguments, but I am having trouble of looping them one by one

Here is an example where the test is

```
subject.orange['orange tray'] do |tray|   
    expect(tray).not_to be_nil

subject.apple['apple tray'] do |tray|   
    expect(tray).not_to be_nil
```

here is what I am trying to do

```
fruits_list = ['orange', 'apple']

fruits_list.each do |fruit|
  subject."#{fruit}[#{fruit} tray]" do |tray|    <------- the error, I can't get this to work
    expect(tray).not_to be_nil
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `send` method, not just hand a string to an object. You could probably do something like:

```
['orange', 'apple'].each do |fruit|
  subject.send(fruit.to_sym)["#{fruit} tray"] do |tray|
    expect(tray).not_to be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much.. wasn't sure what keywords to search for for this and tried multiple things...

Comment: No problem! About a month ago I took a quick glance through the object, hash, and array documentations and have experienced a lot of benefits since. They are, respectively, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html, and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely check those out

Comment: what about subject.exist[:orange_tray] it's not something like subject.exist[:#{fruit}_tray]

Comment: What? That comment doesn't make sense.